# Linking two tables using a foreign key in where one table contains images and the other user info

Tags: mysql

i have two tables: `TableA` contains images and `TableB` contains user information.

TableA

```
 CREATE TABLE `TableA` (
  `picID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `logos` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

TableB

```
 CREATE TABLE `TableB` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_name` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The `foreign key` in `TableA` is `user_id`. And user belongs to a session called members.

```
user_id=".$_SESSION['members']);
```

`picID` is a primary key in `TableA` and `user_id` is the primary key in `TableB`,both set to auto increment and not null.

I would then like to know how to associate the logos in `TableA` to the user table, `TableB`, such that the associated row with an image in `TableA` will only display during the specific user session when I use echo.

In other words, the `user_id` should be associated with the `picID`'s specific row so that every user has his or her own image row with unique images.

But i can't seem to figure out how to link the two tables using my foreign key `user_id` in my database.

Comment: "every user has his or her own image row". if each user can only have 1 image associated, then I don't think you really need a separate table. You can just put the logo field into your user table.

Comment: the code ive posted contains only one image because im trying to understand the logic,but in my project,my image table has 6 images,logo,imageA,ImageB,ImageC,ImageD and header image.ive designed an entire logic where images are also saved and deleted from a folder using unlink.But need to associate the user row to the images uploaded from the image table

Comment: yes ok you have 6 image fields. But you said each user only has one image row associated to them, right?

Comment: yes only one image row,but all images have one id-picID,but different fields for each image.

Comment: right. So if each user only has one image row, then there's really no need for another table. It's a 1 => 1 relationship. Separate tables and foreign keys is mostly only useful if you have a 1 => many relationship (e.g. if the same user_id would appear in multiple rows against different values of picID). If you just put all the image fields into the users table then your stated problem goes away.

Comment: if you don't want to do that for whatever reason, then you just enter the user_id of your user into the right row in the pictures table, and to get all the data from both tables together in a single `SELECT` query you use an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: ok,thanks.this should solve my problem.I just thought that maybe theres a limit to the number of rows in a table.I currently have 21 rows and figured the user table was getting too big

Comment: do you mean the number of columns? 21 is a _tiny_ number of rows. DB tables can hold millions and millions of rows without suffering performance issues. Equally, 21 is not a particularly large number of columns either.

Comment: ok,i had no idea.I am still learning.

Comment: Fair enough. Out of interest, your profile says "senior software engineer". How did you get to that level without ever dealing with a database??

Comment: this is not my account,the owner of the account never uses stackoverflow.He is forever busy coding.I just borrowed this account to learn and get to his level.i guess im ruining his name here.But he doesnt mind me using the account.

Comment: lol you should create your own account. Then you can increase _your_ reputation, not his

Comment: ok,il do that.thank you.just dont ignore me when i ask questions.lol..my account will be called Angela,il create it now

Answer (score 1):

This query will return *all* images associated with each user.

```
     SELECT b.user_id, b.user_name, a.picID, a.logos 
       FROM TableB b
       LEFT JOIN TableA a ON a.user_id = b.user_id
      WHERE b.user_id = $user_id
```

Or, if you only care about the contents of `TableB` in this context do this simpler query:

```
     SELECT a.picID, a.logos 
       FROM TableA a
      WHERE a.user_id = $user_id
      ORDER BY a.picID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Your question beyond that is not clear. Still, I guess you want just one image if a user has multiple images associated with them.

So, you need to decide how you will choose among the images.  One choice is this: choose the latest image for the user.  In that case append this line to either query I just gave you.

```
      ORDER BY a.picID DESC LIMIT 1
```

I define *latest image* here as *image with the highest value of `picID`*.